# When try to upload many images with PrimeFaces <p:fileUpload > I get error

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've the following Jsf:

```html
<!--******************* Button for adding other image ****************-->
    <b:row styleClass="issuer_product_row">
        <b:column col-lg="6" id="imageButton_insert" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
           <h:commandButton id="addImageButton_insert" value=" Image(+) " action="#{cropImageIssuerBean.addImagesData()}">
             <f:ajax execute="@this image_picker_insert" render="@this image_global_insert image_picker_insert" />
           </h:commandButton>
           <h:commandButton id="removeImageButton_insert" action="#{cropImageIssuerBean.removeImagesData()}" value="Image(-) ">
       <f:ajax execute="@this image_picker_insert" render="@this image_global_insert image_picker_insert" />
           </h:commandButton>
    </b:column>
    </b:row>

    <!--******************* Selecting an image ************************-->     
    <b:row id="image_global_insert" styleClass="issuer_product_row">
        <b:column col-lg="6">
           <h:dataTable id="image_picker_insert" var="lpd" value="#{cropImageIssuerBean.lstOfImagesData}" width="100%" first="3">
             <h:column col-lg="6">
             <p:fileUpload id="uploadTag" styleClass="uploadTag" value="#{lpd.uploadedFile}" mode="simple" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/" />
           <div>
             <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
           </div>
       </h:column>
       <h:column col-lg="6">
           <p:colorPicker id="color_picker_insert" value="#{lpd.key}" />
       </h:column>
     <h:column col-lg="6">
    <!--******************* Resizing an image ************************-->
     <h:inputHidden id="crop_image_ih" value="#{lpd.key_2}" />
     </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
     <p:commandButton value="Recadrer" action="#{cropImageIssuerBean.crop()}" ajax="false" />
 </b:column>

<script>
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var $imageCrop = $('#blah').cropper({aspectRatio: 1.2, viewMode: 1, crop: function(e) {                             document.getElementById("issuer_product_add_product_form:crop_image_ih").value = e.x + '/' + e.y + '/' + e.width + '/' + e.height;}});
   reader.onload = function (e) {
    $imageCrop.cropper('replace', e.target.result);  }
    function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files &amp;&amp; input.files[0]) {                   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); }
}
    $(".uploadTag").change(function(){
    readURL(this); });
</script>
```

and the following bean class attribute and function that is used in my Jsf:

```
private List<KeyValueClass> lstOfImagesData;
public String crop() {
    // System.out.println("imagecropproduct =
    // "+cropImageProduct.getIdProduct());

    Product prod = productServices.getOneProduct(cropImageProduct.getIdProduct());
    String rootClass = "com/inductivtechnologies/quantitativemarketingwar/backingbeans/test/RegisterBean.class";
    String path = UtilWebClass.getPathToWebinfFolder(rootClass);
    Map<String, String> imgForColor = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (KeyValueClass kvc : lstOfImagesData) {

        if (kvc.getUploadedFile() != null) {
            try {

                // getting coord.
                String nameFile = kvc.getKey_2();
                String data[] = nameFile.split("/");
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(kvc.getUploadedFile().getContents());
                String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(kvc.getUploadedFile().getFileName());

                System.out.println("rect ======================== " + nameFile);
                System.out.println("teamImg.getSize() ======================== " + kvc.getUploadedFile().getSize());

                BufferedImage bImageFromConvert `enter code here`= ImageIO.read(in);
                // line under this crops. It's possible there is a zoom to
                // figure out, I didn't check yet. Seemed correct on first
                // and only try. In any case you'll figure it out
                // surely the parsing shouldn't be here but I need to sleep
                // real bad.
                BufferedImage croppedImage = bImageFromConvert.getSubimage((int) (Double.parseDouble(data[0])),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(data[1])), (int) (Double.parseDouble(data[2])),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(data[3])));

                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(croppedImage, extension, os);
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

                String fileName = cropImageProduct.getIdProduct().toString() + "." + extension;
                UtilWebClass.copyFile(UtilWebClass.setpathToImgUserFolder(path, fileName), is);

                kvc.setKey_2(nameFile);
                prod.setImage(fileName);
                imgForColor.put(kvc.getKey(), kvc.getKey_2());

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

    }
    prod.setImgForColor(imgForColor);
    productServices.updateProduct(prod);
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Image modifiée avec succès");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fm);

    return "productIssuer";
}
```

When clicking on the validation button that is used to crop and save uploaded images, I get the following error:

> 09:11:25,177 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/quantmarktest].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-80-2) "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Faces Servlet a généré une exception: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert org.primefaces.model.UploadedFileWrapper@6e32afd0 of type class org.primefaces.model.UploadedFileWrapper to interface org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile
>       at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:420) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:204) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:257) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2028) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:1268) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:97) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at com.inductivtechnologies.quantitativemarketingwar.test.filter.RestrictionFilter.doFilter(RestrictionFilter.java:88) [classes:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

**I'll like someone to help me solving that error. Or give me any solution that can help me cropping and saving dynamically images.**

Comment: First of All, Don't use parenthesis with EL expression,                    action="#{cropImageIssuerBean.crop}"

Comment: see this exemple and try it after that you will see [Get uploaded file path in PrimeFaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)

Comment: I've removed parenthesis, I still have the same error. @ArgaPK

Comment: it works when uploading only one image using a single UploadFile attribute instead of a list of UploadFile. in my project, I'ld like to upload and crop images dynamically , by clicking each time on a button that generate upload and colorpicker fields.Validation is done after all images are uploaded. So I created a list of KeyValueClass that is a class containing String attribute  representing color and UploadFile attribute representing the corresponding image. I do not unterdand how  the "org.primefaces.model.UploadedFileWrapper" appear here, while I've not used it in my code. @YagamiLight

Comment: did you exactlly use the primefaces example that is provided in there web site